# Problems with spacing between Yamm navbar and body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently im starting to work with bootstrap 3, but after to read the documentation cant figure it out why the navbar and the next section cant be separated on their own divs.

In this case im using yamm3 for the megamenu and the next part are 3 horizontal search boxes.

Trying to adjust the css, on the body section, the yamm css padding but stills displaying stacked.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/yamm/yamm.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar yamm navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Marca</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Classic list -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Links<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <!-- Content container to add padding -->
              <div class="yamm-content">
                <div class="row">
                  <ul class="col-md-4 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <p><strong> </strong>
                      </p>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="col-md-4 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <p><strong> </strong>
                      </p>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="col-md-4 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <p><strong> </strong>
                      </p>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation link</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Classic dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Classic<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Classic dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" target="_blank">Option 3</a> 
        </li>
        <!-- Classic dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" target="_blank">Corporate</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Classic dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" target="_blank">Option 4</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Classic dropdown -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"><a href="#.html">5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">6</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="employee search" class="col-md-2 control-label">Employee Search</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" action="#" method="POST" target="_blank">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="intranet search" class="col-md-2 control-label">Intranet Search</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" action="#" method="POST" target="_blank">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="keyword entry" class="col-md-2 control-label">Keyword Entry <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <form name="input" action="#" method="GET " target="_blank">
            <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="keyword entry" class="form-control">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">     
     <h2>Loremp Ipsum 2</h2>
     <p>      
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, quisquam ipsa esse temporibus. Cupiditate ipsa modi, nemo tempora dolorem, perferendis impedit, illum quidem vitae quod fuga deleniti. Molestias, culpa molestiae.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add space beneath the navbar, you could add the following to your CSS:

```
.yamm.navbar + section {
    margin-top: 80px; /* or whatever margin you want */
}
```